# Matplotlib Show Display Coordinates

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, coordinates, display

Given a figure like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
f, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)
plt.show()
```

Is it possible to display (via a grid, preferably, or spines) the display coordinates of a figure (not the axis or data coordinates)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mean like a label showing the coordinates?

Comment: Yes, as if I wanted to do plt.text(x,y,'text') and wanted to see where the x and y coordinates would be on the plot.

Answer (score 2):

The following code is a snippet from the [event handling chapter](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/event_handling.html) of matplotlib documentation. Notice that every time you click on the plot there are several values that are printed, including the event coordinates (display coordinates) and plot coordinates.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(np.random.rand(10))

def onclick(event):
    print( 'button=%d, x=%d, y=%d, xdata=%f, ydata=%f'%(
        event.button, event.x, event.y, event.xdata, event.ydata))

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
plt.show()
```

a quick test results in:

```
button=1, x=127, y=98, xdata=0.852823, ydata=0.218149
button=1, x=198, y=228, xdata=2.141129, ydata=0.524111
button=1, x=116, y=382, xdata=0.653226, ydata=0.886559
button=1, x=209, y=371, xdata=2.340726, ydata=0.860669
button=1, x=230, y=257, xdata=2.721774, ydata=0.592364
```

EDIT: You've mentioned a `plt.text` which means you might want to actually display the coordinates on screen. For this you might want to build an [mpl widget](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/widgets_api.html) or just create instances of `plt.text` on the click event (haven't tested it).